# Should I build my own login functionality?

Tags: authentication, passwords, oauth

I've looked at various ways of logging in users and I'm wondering if I should write my own.

There are a lot of third party solutions that make it easy and cheap to get started, like Amazon Cognito and Auth0. But as easy as it is to get started, they all lock you in, make you reliant on their solutions and have terribly one sided user agreements (in their favor).

There are a some open source solutions that offer a complete experience out of the box, like Keycloak. It works but it's highly opinionated about flows like email verification and its freemarker templates would take a major effort to style as we want. ORY Kratos also comes to mind, but it's in the early stages and I don't want to rely on a project they I don't know at this point if it will be around in a few years. I hope it will because it looks promising.

Spring Security used to be an option but unfortunately their current solution is deprecated.

So... should I roll my own?

It seems like bad practice, but I find it difficult to find concrete arguments. If I google the question, I find arguments against in house authentication solutions like having to hash passwords and having to write features like email verification and password reset. However, all of these would be easy to implement, so these particular examples aren't convincing reasons not to create an in house solution.

But maybe there are a lot of unknown unknowns that I should worry about?

For instance, OAuth / OIDC + PKCE have some complex flows that I can't claim to understand. Maybe these are all things we need, or maybe they're not.

What are your thoughts? Is an in house authentication solution feasible? Or should I forget about it, bite the bullet and put an Amazon/Auth0 snare around my neck? Other solutions?

Comment: *"login functionality"* is a pretty broad description and it is not clear what you really need in the first place. But given your arguments so far I'm not sure that you have the knowledge and resources to write your own solution in the first place and make sure that it is actually secure. If this is true it would be a clear argument against writing your own.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to provide answers on specific question. You are asking about *opinions*. Such questions are out of scope on this site.

Comment: I'm asking for concrete arguments. Those should not be opinion based.

Comment: @Martin01478: *"I'm asking for concrete arguments."* - Not enough details are known to provide concrete arguments, neither about the specific requirements for the *"login functionality"* nor about your capabilities to implement one by your own and to maintain it yourself in the future. Solutions are usually not perfect but a trade-off with various advantages and disadvantages. And there are a variety of restrictions in real-life, i.e. business needs, time to market, available money ... and many of these considerations are unrelated to security (i.e. off-topic).

Comment: @Martin01478: Rereading your question ... basically none of the arguments you provide is related to security. These are about price, availability in future, ease of use, user agreements, stage of development, ... . Valid arguments, but unrelated to security. Not considering security as the main point of decision (or even worse: not considering security at all) makes the question off-topic in my opinion.

Comment: _"having to hash passwords and having to write features like email verification and password reset. However, all of these would be easy to implement"_ Easy to implement? Sure. Easy to implement securely? Not as much. An advantage of using a dedicated solution or an existing framework is that they have likely already addressed common pitfalls that you may not be aware of.

Comment: This is ridiculous. What security features should be part of a modern login functionality (mainly authentication) is most certainly NOT opinion based. If you are unable to provide a meaningful answer, don't blame the question. Just move on and let someone with something meaningful to add answer the question.

Comment: Please do not editorialise in posts.

Comment: Your question is literally "should I?", and "what are your thoughts?", which is inherently opinion-based. You offer no specific requirements, requiring people to guess, and you ask to know about unknown unknowns, which is completely unbounded. This is a perfect example of an opinion-based question. "Is it feasible?" Well, with absolutely no context, the answer is, of course, yes. And no...

Comment: @schroeder Your incorrect description is based on the title, ignoring the text which provides context. If you are unable to fill in blanks in a meaningful way: don't. That does not mean that someone who makes a more generous interpretation cannot. But quit providing pointless distraction and arguments.

Comment: No, it's based on the question. Don't assume what my basis is.

Comment: I'm trying to explain why it is closed so that you can possibly improve it. I'm not trying to engage in argument or semantics. I'm providing a requirement and pointing out the issues to resolve.

Comment: There is no assumption, I based my answer on what you wrote. And you are still wasting energy providing pointless argumentation.

Comment: "Your incorrect description is based on the title, ignoring the text which provides context." -- this is literally an assumption. Take a breath. Don't focus on the people in your way. Focus on the question, the feedback provided, and focus on how to improve the question.

Comment: I know the people who gatekeep this site love questions that provide so much information that they can be trivially answered. In other words, questions that are barely worth asking. Broad questions require whoever answers to fill in blanks. This is more difficult. But those blanks should be based on experience, not opinion. Clearly you have nothing meaningful to add. So just don't.

Comment: And so the question will remain closed. Have a nice day.

Comment: And so rather than seeing if someone has something meaningful to add, you decide that because you can't provide any value, no one can. You people make this site nearly pointless.

Comment: Pointless for you. In this instance. Sure. I can buy that. That's ok. But be careful not to make this all about you and attack the people who are trying to help. If you keep doing that, then this site has to exclude you from it. Stay classy.

Comment: @Martin01478 You might want to drop by in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz). Questions that are closed on the site might still get answered in chat (however, do note that I can't guarantee you'll get an answer.)